# Calling an object in a search method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, regex, hash

I am searching through an array of hashes and I need to find specific objects within the hash. The issue is that I am getting what I need to search from another model. Currently I am searching like this...

```
@insur_transactions = user.transactions.find_all { |t| (t.fetch('name').downcase! =~ /user.bill.name/) }
```

the problem is this wont search the hashes with the object found in bill.name. How do I get it to pull that object from the bill model and search that specific item? I am using mongoid for my db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer. SInce this is using regex you can pull an object by using /#{ object }/ So my code looks like this

```
@insur_transactions = user.transactions.find_all { |t| (t.fetch('name').downcase! =~ /#{user.bill.name}/) }
```

That got it!